# Limits and functions. Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $x_0, l$, and $m$ be in $\mathbb R$. Assume that $f$ is defined on a deleted nbh of $x_0$ with $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = l$. let $g$ be defined on a nbh of $l$.

(a) Carefully show that $g(f)$ is defined on a deleted nbh of $x_0$

(b) If $\lim_{x\to l} g(x) = m$ and $g(l) = m$, show that

$\lim_{x\to x_0} g(f(x)) = m$.

I don't even know where to start with this. A push in the right direction would be helpful!

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Literally haven't even tried anything. This question hurts my brain.

Comment: It's alright if you don't know how to start, but maybe you can at least say something about what parts, definitions, etc. are the most confusing to you.

Answer (score 1):

A neighborhood of $l$ is a set of points $y$ such that $|y - l| < \epsilon_0$ for some fixed $\epsilon_0 > 0$. (in other words, $|y - l| < \epsilon_0$ for all $y$ in $(l - \epsilon_0, l + \epsilon_0)$.)

Because $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = l$, this means there is a $\delta$ so that $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon_0$ whenever $|x - x_0| < \delta$. (in other words, $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon_0$ for all $x$ in $(x_0 - \delta,x_0 + \delta)$, and I'm taking it as implicit that $f$ is defined on this interval; if not, just choose a smaller $\delta$)

Then, I claim $(x_0 - \delta,x_0 + \delta)$ is a deleted neighborhood of $x_0$ on which $g(f)$ is defined. Indeed, if you start with a point $x \in (x_0 - \delta,x_0 + \delta)$, then $f(x)$ is well defined, and $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon_0$. This last statement is the same as saying $f(x) \in (l - \epsilon_0, l+\epsilon_0)$, which is the neighborhood where $g$ is defined; thus $g(f(x))$ "makes sense", and thus the composition $g(f)$ is defined on $(x_0 - \delta,x_0 + \delta)$ as claimed.